# How to order names in a column based on an index sequence in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So I have 3 tables **Friends** and **Students** and they both have an **ID** column. But in the **Friends** table, there is also a column known as **Friend_ID**. I want to reorder the **Name** column in **Friends** in the way the **Friend_ID** is ordered. Is it possible?

This is for the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/placements/problem?isFullScreen=false

Note: I want to use this **without** the **ORDER BY** clause as this will be a subquery.

My query in SQL Server.

```
WITH 
    CTE (NID,N_Name,N_Salary,FID) AS
    (SELECT S.ID AS NID, S.Name AS N_Name, P.Salary AS N_Salary, F.Friend_ID AS FID 
     FROM Students S JOIN Friends F
     ON S.ID = F.ID JOIN Packages P 
     ON S.ID = P.ID),
     
     
--SELECT L.NID,L.N_Name,L.N_Salary,L.FID,R.FN_Sal
SELECT 
   IIF(L.N_Salary > R.FN_Sal,
       IIF(L.FID IN (SELECT ID FROM Students WHERE Students.ID=R.N_ID),L.N_Name,"No val")
    ,NULL)

FROM CTE L
JOIN 
    (SELECT F.ID AS N_ID, P.Salary AS FN_Sal, F.Friend_ID AS F_ID 
     FROM Friends F JOIN Packages P ON F.Friend_ID = P.ID) R
ON L.NID = R.N_ID
```

[image]

I guess there is something wrong with my query. This is definitely not an elegant solution but I am just trying out an idea. Any input would be really helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the question is a little bit hazy, can you provide a table with what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I will make the edits to the question. See @Giannis, I am trying to use this query as a subquery in another query. Hence I don't want to use the ORDER BY clause. This is for a Hackerrank problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `Students` to `Friends` and to 2 copies of `Packages`.
The 1st copy of `Packages` will return the student's salary and the 2nd copy will return the friend's salary:

```
SELECT s.Name
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Friends f ON f.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN Packages ps ON ps.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN Packages pf ON pf.ID = f.Friend_ID
WHERE pf.Salary > ps.Salary
ORDER BY pf.Salary
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e14dfdee1711d6c4c58d6571e87ab56a).
Results:

```
> | Name     |
> | :------- |
> | Samantha |
> | Julia    |
> | Scarlet  |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one answer to the question:

```sql
DECLARE @Friends TABLE (ID int, Friend_ID INT);
DECLARE @Students TABLE (ID int, Name VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @Packages TABLE (ID int, Salary DECIMAL(4,2));

INSERT INTO @Friends SELECT ID,Friend_ID FROM (VALUES(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)) Friends(ID,Friend_ID);
INSERT INTO @Students SELECT ID,[Name] FROM (VALUES(1,'Ashley'),(2,'Samantha'),(3,'Julia'),(4,'Scarlet')) Students(ID,[Name]);
INSERT INTO @Packages SELECT ID,Salary FROM (VALUES (1,15.20),(2,10.06),(3,11.55),(4,12.12)) Packages(ID,Salary);

WITH StudentPackage AS (
    SELECT
        Student.ID,
        Student.[Name] StudentName,
        Packages.Salary,
        BestFriend.Friend_ID 
    FROM @Students Student
    JOIN @Packages Packages
    ON Student.ID = Packages.ID
    JOIN @Friends BestFriend
    ON Student.ID = BestFriend.ID
)
SELECT
    Student.StudentName
FROM StudentPackage Student
JOIN StudentPackage BestFriend
ON Student.Friend_ID = BestFriend.ID AND BestFriend.Salary > Student.Salary
ORDER BY BestFriend.Salary
```

Comment: So the idea is to make a CT exp. and then make a join with the previous table (used in the CTE)?

Comment: I think this is one way of solving your problem but it would be easier if you post the whole question.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/placements/problem?isFullScreen=false here is the question. I know my approach is not simple, rather a bit too complex. But I still want to see if it is possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think this is one aproach to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey @Andreas, thanks! This has a way simpler approach than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Order by clause. That should work.

Comment: I have used the Order By clause but I would like to use something else as I want to use this in a subquery.

Comment: More of a comment

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your inputs! They are correct and I see how unnecessarily I have complicated such a simple question.

This is the solution I was trying to achieve, according to my logic:

```
WITH 
    CTE (N_ID,N_Name,N_Salary,FID) AS
    (SELECT S.ID AS N_ID, S.Name AS N_Name, P.Salary AS N_Salary, F.Friend_ID AS FID 
     FROM Students S JOIN Friends F
     ON S.ID = F.ID JOIN Packages P 
     ON S.ID = P.ID)
     
     
SELECT L.N_Name
FROM CTE L
JOIN 
    (SELECT F.ID AS N_ID, P.Salary AS FN_Sal, F.Friend_ID AS F_ID 
     FROM Friends F JOIN Packages P ON F.Friend_ID = P.ID) R
ON L.N_ID = R.N_ID
WHERE R.FN_Sal > L.N_Salary
ORDER BY R.FN_Sal;
```